# How to cancel/abort Cassandra query?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

In NodeJS Cassandra code, while handling callbacks for each row from `client.stream()` or `client.eachRow()`, what is the proper way to stop iterating? How do I tell the client object that I am no longer interested in the results. It might even be worthwhile to raise an 'error' or 'done' event.

Also, would there be any problems with nodejs-driver if, while processing a row in an async fashion, the code starts another query using the same client object?

Answer (score 3):

With `client.stream` you are working with a [stream.Readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) so you can call [pause()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) on the stream however, the driver will continue parsing and buffering data and pulling in new pages as it goes (assuming autopaging is enabled).

When using `client.stream` and `client.eachRow` you can provide an [autoPage](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/nodejs/2.1/global.html#QueryOptions) option to determine whether or not the driver keeps paging when it hits the end of a page.  If you are concerned about reading too much data from a large result set, you can use the pageState of the previous query for the next query (example [here](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/v2.1.2/test/integration/short/client-each-row-tests.js#L293)).  Unfortunately this wont work for `client.stream` yet ([NODEJS-145](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/NODEJS-145)).

> Also, would there be any problems with nodejs-driver if, while processing a row in an async fashion, the code starts another query using the same client object?

That will not be a problem :)